# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(2))$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be a twice differentiable decreasing function such that $f''(x)$ is positive for $x\in(1,\infty)$. For each positive integer $n$, let $a_n$ denote the area of the region bounded by the graph of $f$ and the line segment joining the points $(n,f(n)$ and $(n+1,f(n+1))$. Show that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(2))$.

My attempt: I can see that

$a_n=f(n+1)+\frac{1}{2}(f(n)-f(n+1))-\int_n^{n+1}f(n)$

$=\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(n+1))-\int_n^{n+1}f(n)$

$<\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(n+1))-f(n+1)$

which is somewhat helpful in the infinite sum as many terms cancel, but I'm not getting the right bound. How can I use the second derivative being negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am jumping directly to the step where you have reached.

$$a_n=f(n+1)+\frac{1}{2}(f(n)-f(n+1))-\int_n^{n+1}f(n)$$

Now $\int_n^{n+1}f(n)$ represents the area under the graph from $n$ to $n+1$.

If we replace it by a smaller quantity, then we will increase its value.

But from what value should we replace it? You have used $f(n+1)$ but it doesn't give required result .So let us use graphs.This is a random decreasing convex graph.

[image: This is a random decreasing convex graph.]

Here that blue line is tangent to the curve at point $B(n+1,f(n+1))$
Let us subtract the area enclosed by the curve $ABD$.

Now, what we are left with is $\int_n^{n+1} \text{ Line} BD $.

On integrating the line

$y=f'(n+1)x+f(n+1)-f'(n+1)(n+1)$

On $n$ to $n+1$, what we get is :

$$\int_n^{n+1}f'(n+1)x+f(n+1)-f'(n+1)(n+1)=f(n+1)-\frac {f'(n+1)}{2}$$

(Notice, f'(n+1) is negative here.)

Now we are done.

$$\implies a_n = \frac  {(f(n)+f(n+1))}{2}-\int_n^{n+1}f(n)$$

$$\implies a_n < \frac {1}{2}(f(n)+f(n+1))-(f(n+1)-\frac {f'(n+1)}{2})$$

$$ \implies a_n < \frac{1}{2}(f(n)-f(n+1))+\frac {f'(n+1)}{2}$$

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg[\frac{1}{2}(f(n)-f(n+1))+\frac {f'(n+1)}{2}\Bigg]$$

$$ \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n< \lim _{m \rightarrow \infty}\Bigg[ \frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(m))+\ \sum_{n=1}^m \Bigg (\frac {f'(n+1)}{2}\Bigg )\Bigg]$$

Now, hold on for a minute. Notice:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg (\frac {f'(n+1)}{2}\Bigg )$$

can be approximated as -

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac {f'(n+1)}{2}$$

(using sum as integration since $1,2,3...$ are very small intervals as compared to $\infty$)

Continue :

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n< \lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg[\frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(m))+\int_1^{m} \frac {f'(n+1)}{2} \Bigg]$$

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n< \lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg[\frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(m))+ \frac {f(n+1)}{2} \Bigg |_{1}^{m} \Bigg ]$$

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<  \frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(m))+ \frac {f(m)-f(1+1)}{2}$$

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<  \frac{1}{2}(f(1)-f(2))$$

Finally, done with it!

Answer (score 0):

On each interval $[n,n+2]$, since $f$ is convex, $f$ is above its tangent line at $n+1$ (see property 5 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)), hence for all $x\in [n,n+2]$, $$ f(x) \geq f(n+1)+ f'(n+1)(x-(n+1))$$
Integrating this inequality over $x$, 
$$\int_{n}^{n+2}f(x) dx \geq \int_{n}^{n+2} [f(n+1)+ f'(n+1)(x-(n+1))]dx$$
which rewrites $$\int_n^{n+2} f(x)dx \geq 2f(n+1)$$

Remember that $$a_n=\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(n+1))-\int_n^{n+1}f(n)$$

Hence $$\begin{align} a_n+a_{n+1} &= \frac{f(n)+f(n+1)}2 + \frac{f(n+1)+f(n+2)}2 - \int_{n}^{n+2} f(x)dx\\
&\leq \frac{f(n)+f(n+1)}2 + \frac{f(n+1)+f(n+2)}2 - 2f(n+1) \\
&=\frac{f(n)-f(n+1)}2 - \frac{f(n+1)-f(n+2)}2
\end{align} $$

Since $f$ is decreasing and positive, it has a finite limit at $\infty$ hence $\frac{f(n+1)-f(n+2)}2$ converges to $0$.

Summing all these inequalities, the sums on the right telescope, yielding $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{n+1})\leq \frac{f(1)-f(2)}2$$
that is $$\left( 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \right) -a_1 \leq \frac{f(1)-f(2)}2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \leq \frac{f(1)-f(2)}4 + \frac{a_1}2$$
The bound you found in your question yields $\displaystyle a_1\leq \frac{f(1)-f(2)}2$ and we're done.

Comment: I could not get why for a decreasing function having second derivative positive the inequality$$\int_{n}^{n+2}f \geq \int_{n}^{n+2} [f(n+1)+ f'(n+1)(x-(n+1))]dx$$ holds. Can you please explain a bit over it and how it simplifies . Thanks.

Comment: @navinstudent I've added all the details.

Comment: @downvoter ????

Comment: I think it would be better if you add telescoping sum. 
Telescoping sum results in : 
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+a_{n+1})\leq \frac{f(1)-f(2)}2 - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n+1)-f(n+2)}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following figure, where the area $a_n$ is shaded in red:

[image]

Convexity implies that the area $a_n$ is contained in the triangle $\triangle ABC$. It follows that
$$\eqalign{a_n&\leq {\rm area}(\triangle ABC)={1\over2}\bigl(f(n)-2f(n+1)+f(n+2)\bigr)\cr&={1\over2}\bigl(f(n)-f(n+1)\bigr)-{1\over2}\bigl(f(n+1)-f(n+2)\bigr)\ .\cr}$$
Summing over $n$ gives on the right hand side a (convergent) telescopic sum, so that we obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\leq{1\over2}\bigl(f(1)-f(2)\bigr)\ .$$